# Do you have to truncate all tables every time an OLAP Cube is beeing rebuilt?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, olap, cube

Our OLAP Cube processing has become pretty slow in the last few months, so I'd like to try to optimize it. My former co-worker, who had modified it a bit and showed me where to find the package and how to read it, isn't here anymore and when he showed it, I had just started with SQL, so I didn't really understand most of it. When I now look at the steps, I think I understand how it works and the whole process starts with truncating all the tables that are needed for the cube and re-importing them.

Is there a specific reason for this? We are still on SQL Server 2008 and the Cube is getting it's data from a Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 Database. The main table (InventTrans) has 156mil records and is 95GB big with 246GB of Indexes. Is it really necessary to reload that whole table every night? Could I not simply exclude that table from the truncation-process and instead just delete the last 2 years and then only add the newest data?

I remember him telling me that the enterprise-version of SQL server has a built in process for this, but why did he not do it manually back then? Checking some of his code from back then it seems to me that he also was pretty new to SQL so I'm not sure if it has a technical reason or if he didn't feel confident enough to try it, since the Cube was built by a company 7 years ago.

Comment: Basically the truncation is not required for the processing! However, depending on how the ETL is structured, it might be required in order to get the most recent data. Nevertheless, this is something for a redesign of the ETL, not the cube itself (defining some kind of delta load or something). So you will have to distinguish between the ETL itself (importing / loading data into the tables) and the Cube-Processing. If your data is date-dependent, you might consider partitioning your cube by a date range (e.g. per week) - this gives you the possibility to only process changed weeks.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i had in mind. It is date-dependent, so I'll try to update only the last year.